# SQL Server View Execution Plan: Is WHERE OR the Same as UNION?

Tags: sql-server

I have a view that is a collection of joins. For the purposes of this question I will simplify the view as follows. Note, `Table1.Table1ID` is the primary key, `Table2.Table1ID` is the foreign key.

```
CREATE VIEW [View1] AS
SELECT t1.Column1, t2.Column2
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Table1ID = t2.Table1ID
```

Using a view for this purpose is nice because it reduces the number of joins I have to do in my code and it allows SQL Server to more efficiently optimize the joins. For example:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM View1
WHERE Column1 = 'abc'
AND Column2 = 'xyz'
GROUP BY Column1, Column2
```

SQL Server optimizes the above query by joining only the subset of records from Table1 where the value in Column1 is 'abc' and the subset of records from Table2 where the value in Column2 is 'xyz'. In other words, the SQL Server execution plan smartly applies the filtering to the respective tables in the view before applying the join, thus reducing the number of records that need to be accounted for in the join.

If, however, I alter the former query by changing the `AND` operator in the `WHERE` clause to an `OR` operator, the execution plan does *not* apply the filtering before performing the join.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM View1
WHERE Column1 = 'abc'
OR Column2 = 'xyz'
GROUP BY Column1, Column2
```

The execution plan for the above query joins all records from Table1 and Table2 first and then applies the where clause second. This complies with Boolean logic, because the `OR` operator test cannot be satisfied until the tables are joined and the values in both Column1 and Column2 are present and accounted for.

On the other hand, the following query returns the same result set as the former query.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM View1
WHERE Column1 = 'abc'
UNION
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM View1
WHERE Column2 = 'xyz'
```

The latter two queries yield the same result, but the second of the two is optimized by SQL Server such that the execution plan applies the where clauses to the respective tables in the respective `SELECT` statements before the join is spplied in the view, resulting in fewer records being joined. This results in a more efficient query overall even though the view is actually being called twice and the intersection of the resulting record sets is being returned by a `UNION`.

My questions are:

- Why doesn't SQL Server optimize the second to last query using an execution plan that resembles the last query?
- Is there a way to define the view such that SQL Server optimizes it using an execution plan that resembles the last query?

Thank you.

Comment: The final query is *not* equivalent - because `UNION` eliminates duplicates - I'm guessing you have no duplicates *in your test data*, but that's not a generally safe assumption.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Good catch. I left off a critical part. The `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE ... OR ...` is a different query from `UNION`. If a single row has values `abc` in `Column1` and `xyz` in `Column2` it will produce only one row in the `WHERE ... OR ...` case but two rows in the `UNION` case. You may argue that the `UNION` removes duplicates (since is not `UNION ALL`), I say this is a simplified example that omits other columns being projected. But even considering this example ad-literam I can then give another case where *two* rows have the values `abc` for `Column1` and `xyz` for `Column2` and in such case the first query returns two rows while the second returns 1. QED, the optimization you expect cannot happen because is incorrect.

Comment: Apologies. I left off a critical part of the initial queries. The `GROUP BY` clause. Any time I query from the view, I `GROUP BY` all of the columns that I select so that I get a discrete record set.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't SQL Server optimize the second to last query using an execution plan that resembles the last query?

It could do a transformation that is similar to the example you provided. You'd need to work out the details mentioned in Remus' answer. I'm pretty sure that's doable. For example you can use the fact that you can rewrite a `UNION` to a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. That allows you to insert the right deduplication conditions.

This transformation is not implemented as of 2012. This is unfortunate, but the product team cannot deliver a perfect optimizer anyway. What we have is pretty good.

> Is there a way to define the view such that SQL Server optimizes it using an execution plan that resembles the last query?

Not that I know of.

I know that this answer does not improve things for you but that's the situation. For now, consider creating an indexed view. That way you can pre-generate the subset of rows you are interested in. You can create indexes that span columns of multiple tables. You can index expressions.